# Azure: could not load file or assembly, nothing helps

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I got WebAPI asp.net project. On my dev machine everything is working fine, but when I am trying to deploy it to Azure I got `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)` exception. I've done all advises from other such questions: I've updated packages, added binding redirect:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but that doesnt help. I am publishing app using TeamcCity -> Octopus and could see that in publish package System.Web.Http is present.

Comment: Are you sure that the required version is present??

Comment: @IpsitGaur yes System.Web.Http version 5.2.30128.0 is there. Ive tried made redirect as  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.30128.0" /> - thats doesnt help.